# Iterating over array of objects with react

Tags: reactjs, object

I have a data object that I need to be able to iterate over which is an array of objects. I'm attempting to do so with `Object.keys`, but missing something with my implementation, as I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'metrics' of undefined`.

The data object is constructed as such:

```
export const data = {
  metrics:
  [
    {
      number:'10',
      subText: 'content',
      tertiary: 'more content'
    },
    {...}
  ]
}
```

where the component is trying to iterate over the object like so:

```
 export const Metrics = (props) => {
  return (
      <div className="metric-container" aria-labelledby="metrics">
        {Object.keys(props.data.metrics).map((metric, i) => (
          <div className="metric"><h1>{metric.number}</h1><p>{metric.subText}</p><p>{metric.tertiary}</p></div>
        ))}
      </div>
    )
};
```

the data is imported into App.js with

```
import { data } from './assets/dataprops';
```

that has the component `<Metrics {...data}/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Metrics {...data}/>
```

This passes each of the keys in `data` as props to `Metrics`. You can make one of two changes:

1. Access `props.metrics` instead of `props.data.metrics`.
2. Pass `data` as a prop:

   ```
   <Metrics data={data}>
   ```

I suggest that you install the React Developer plugin for your browser. This adds a "React" tab to the developer tools window. On this tab, you can inspect components and their props and state. Using this tool helps you track down problems like the one you encountered here. You would immediately see that the `Metrics` component has no prop named `data` but that it does have a prop named `metrics`.

Note that since `metrics` is an array, you do not need to call `Object.keys()`. You can simply do `props.metrics.map()` directly.

Comment: Using `props.metrics.map()` directly was the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
<Metrics data={...data}/>
```

Otherwise, if you want to pass

```
<Metrics {...data}/>
```

You can access metrics like

```
 export const Metrics = (props) => {
  return (
      <div className="metric-container" aria-labelledby="metrics">
        {Object.keys(props.metrics).map((metric, i) => (
          <div className="metric"><h1>{metric.number}</h1><p>{metric.subText}</p><p>{metric.tertiary}</p></div>
        ))}
  </div>
)
```

};

Comment: I went with the second option, and removed data from `props.data.metrics` so that its just `props.metrics`, but now none of the data is showing in the DOM.

Comment: @Matt It could be, because you don't a key in your `<div className="metric">` ?